# Getting all items of app with python library does not work

Tags: python, podio

```
from pypodio2 import api

# Authenticate as App
podio_client = api.OAuthAppClient(
    client_id=PODIO_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=PODIO_CLIENT_SECRET,
    app_id=PODIO_APP_ID,
    app_token=PODIO_APP_TOKEN,    
)

# Set limit to 100
items = podio_client.Item.filter(app_id=PODIO_APP_ID, attributes={}, limit=100)
```

My app has a total of 251 items and I expect that the API would return 100 items but it only returns 20... How to fix this?

> print(items['total'])
>
> 251
>
> print(items['filtered'])
>
> 251
>
> print(len(items['items'])
>
> 20

**Update**

I tried it with the requests library but still no success...

```
import requests
payload = {
  "filters":{},
  "limit": 30
}
resp = requests.post(url="https://api.podio.com/item/app/randomappid/filter/", 
                    headers={'authorization': 'OAuth2 randomn0mber'},
                    data=payload)
```

> len(resp.json()['items'])
>
> 20

API call docs: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your items object ? from a first glance, it only looks like your object items has a key 'items' that holds 20 elements.

Comment: The object `items` has three keys: total, filtered and items. `Total` indicates how much items the application has, `filtered` says how much items are left after applying the filter and `items` has al the items. I want to get 251 items by applying no filter, I added the 100 limit to show that it is broken because I only get 20 items.

Comment: Shouldn't the items['filtered'] return 100 items as well?

Comment: @nimish666 It only contains an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`limit` must pass thru the `attributes` parameter.

```
# Set limit to 100
items = podio_client.Item.filter(app_id=PODIO_APP_ID, attributes={"limit": 100})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but using the [deprecated api call](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-items-27803) I get the desired results... Would still like to know how to do it using the filter api call.

```
params = {"limit": 300}
resp = requests.get(url="https://api.podio.com/item/app/randomappid/", 
                    headers={'authorization': 'OAuth2 randomn0mber'},
                    params=params)
```

> len(resp.json()['items'])
>
> 251